# Type checking broken on matching capture with upper bound?

Tags: java, java-8, typechecking

Create a class like

```
public class Play {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        outer(Integer.class, inner("abc"));
    }

    static <C> void outer(Class<C> c, List<? super C> s){
    }

    static <C> List<C> inner(C c) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and it compiles in Java 8! (Both in Eclipse 4.5 and JDK1.8_25) https://ideone.com/Q9JLHP

In Eclipse, all the bounds are inferred correctly, but how could `outer`'s capture `Supplier<? super Integer>` ever been satisfied by the argument `Supplier<String>`??

Edit: clarified this is Java 8-specific and made the example less confusing.

Comment: @bayou.io It's just arbitrary generic type I picked for the example. I am sure the compiler does not treat it specially here. I'll update the example to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`inner("abc")` can, at the compiler's discretion, be interpreted as a `Supplier` of any supertype of `String`. -- for example,

```
Supplier<Object> inner = inner("abc");
```

works just fine, because `"abc"` is *also* an `Object`.  That's what's happening here: `inner` is returning you a `Supplier<Object>`.

Comment: But this behaviour seems to be new to Java 8. Any reference to why this change was made? Because it has broken type checking on Hamcrest's `assertThat()`, which is commonly used.

Comment: Java 8 has [target type inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101), which lets type inference information propagate down the AST as well as up.  This is pretty much strictly necessary to make lambdas magically figure out the right type for their context as a general thing.

Comment: Besides helping lambda expressions, it solves the flaws that existed since the introduction of Generics, i.e. as you couldn’t write `List<Number> l=Arrays.asList(42);` or `List<T> l=condition? …: Collections.emptyList();`, etc. If it breaks existing code, it’s the existing code which is flawed as the same code would have passed the older compiler when the inferred type will be inserted manually, i.e. here by saying `outer(Integer.class, Play.<Object>inner("abc"));`

Answer (score 1):

Inference on `inner` requires that `C` is a supertype of `Integer` and `String`.

What is `C` exactly? That is a complicated story. Both `Integer` and `String` are `Object`, of course. But both are `Serializable` too! and `Comparable<?>` too....

In the end, it doesn't matter much; all we need to know is that it is a "least upper bound" of `String` and `Integer`, in whatever way it is [defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4).

Comment: `C` doesn't have to be a supertype of `Integer` and `String`. The `List` in `outer`'s signature just has to contain elements of some unspecified supertype of `Integer` and `String`.